# How can i extract Href and title from this HTML

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

my bs4.element.ResultSet has this format:

```
    [<h3 class="foo1">
    <a href="someLink" title="someTitle">SomeTitle</a>
    </h3>,
    <h3 class="foo1">
    <a href="OtherLink" title="OtherTitle">OtherTitle</a>
    </h3>]
```

and i want to be able to extract and save in tuple
[(title,href),(title2, href2)] but i cant seem to do so

my closest attempt was

```
    link = soup.find('h3',class_='foo1').find('a').get('title')
    print(link)
```

but that only returns the first element of the 2 or more
how can i successfully extract each href and title

Comment: Uhm... `[i.find("a")["title"] for i in soup.find_all("h3")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your elements more specific e.g. with `css selectors` and iterate over your `ResultSet` to get the attributes of each of them as list of `tuples`:

```
[(a.get('title'),a.get('href')) for a in soup.select('h3 a[href][title]')]
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''
<h3 class="foo1">
    <a href="someLink" title="someTitle">SomeTitle</a>
</h3>
<h3 class="foo1">
    <a href="OtherLink" title="OtherTitle">OtherTitle</a>
</h3>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

[(a.get('title'),a.get('href')) for a in soup.select('h3 a[href]')]
```

##### Output

```
[('someTitle', 'someLink'), ('OtherTitle', 'OtherLink')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```py
soup.select('h3.foo1>a[href][title]').map(lambda link : (link.get("href"), link.get("title")))
```

Explanation:

```py
soup.select('h3.foo1>a[href][title]')
```

Selects all the `a` elements that have a `href` and a `title` that are a direct child of an `h3` element with the `foo1` class.

```py
.map(lambda link :
```

For each of those `a` elements, replace each of them with what follows.

```py
(link.get("href"), link.get("title"))
```

Make a tuple containing the link's `href` and `title`.